# Using WebAudio as data for vertex shader in WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader, web-audio-api

I'm hoping to use the data from an AnalyserNode in WebAudio as the input for my vertex shader in WebGL, but I'm really at a loss for how I'd go about doing this. I've got it working for a simple .jpg using the following code, so I'm wondering how best to pass frequency and waveform data to my fragment shader.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id='vertexShader'>
    uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
    void main() {

        vec4 textureDisplacement = texture2D(iChannel0, uv);

        vec3 newPosition = position + normal * (textureDisplacement.xyz * 10.0);

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.);
    }
</script>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
var container,
material,
renderer,
scene,
camera,
mesh,
start = Date.now(),
    fov = 30;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    // grab the container from the DOM
    container = document.getElementById("container");


    // create a scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create a camera the size of the browser window
    // and place it 100 units away, looking towards the center of the scene
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    fov,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    10000);
    camera.position.z = 100;
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    scene.add(camera);

    // create a wireframe material    
    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

        uniforms: {
            iChannel0: {
                type: 't',
                value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('simplex.jpg')
            }
        },
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading

    });


    // create a sphere and assign the material
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 20, 4 ), 
    material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // create the renderer and attach it to the DOM
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antiAliasing: true,
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x222222, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    animate();

});

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // let there be light
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

This is the image I'm using as my sampler2D input:
http://members.gamedev.net/vertexnormal/techimages/seamless.jpg

Comment: The AnalyserNode will give you a Float32Array of samples, which in plain WebGL you could directly set as the data for a shader attribute using gl.bufferData. But I'm not sure if a three.js ShaderMaterial can take a Float32Array for attribute values, or if you'd have to copy it to a plain JavaScript array.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you want it to actually do with the audio data.

Comment: I think that Threejs DataTexture could come in help: http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Textures/DataTexture.
Then, all you have to do is to pass the data as a `sampler2D ` uniform type.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I ended up doing @S.C.